# Multiple filter groups

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm using *Reporting Services 2005* and I'm in need of your expertise!

I have a data set acquired using a stored procedure that I need to segment into groups depending on a range of conditions. All conditions are unfortunately autonomic in the sense that they all don't logically correlate (it's not just the same filter with different arguments.) To make it all worse, I need to put  page breaks after *some* of the groups.

Sample conditions:

```
Group 1: rows with column0 set to 'dummy-data0'
Group 2: rows with column1 set to 'dummy-data1'
Group 3: rows with column0 set to 'dummy-data2'
Group 4: rows with column2 set to 'dummy-data3' and include page break
Group 5: rows with column0 set to 'dummy-data4'

...and so forth.
```

I've tried to add two groups to the same row, without avail and I've tried to add groups by the row's property pane.

How would you suggest that I sort this out?

I've only fiddled with this a for a few days, and I'd be very appreciative for what help you can offer me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understand, but if you would like to filter the same dataset with multiple different filters for different data regions in the report I would set the dataset as the dataset for all of the data regions and then I would apply filters to the data regions to return only the data you want for each data region.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152832%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Does this help?

Comment: This is essentially how I resolved this issue. I created multiple tables and used filters to filter their population. Unfortunately this meant that I lost the floating headers, but for this use case it's an acceptable loss. Thanks